# Grounding switches

Tags: electrical, grounding

If a metal receptacle has 2+ switches but they are all on the same circuit, is it necessary to ground the receptacle to each one (or ground each one to the receptacle) or is it enough to just ground it to one of them? IOW, do I need to wire each one's ground to the receptacle or just for one of them?

[image]

Comment: When you say receptacle, do you mean box?

Answer (score 1):

The grounding terminal on all the switches should be connected to the box, and to the grounding conductor for the circuit. This is most often achieved using pigtails, though could technically be achieved using a long piece of grounding conductor.